# Linq to entities does not recognize my entity types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a problem when creating an entity model from scratch. I successfully design my objects and generate the database creation. But when I try to make a linq request like

```
var t = from e in entity.UsersSet
        where e.Id == 1
        select e;
```

it seems like my 'e' variable is not recognized as a User object whereas my UsersSet property is of ObjectSet type.
If I stop my expression typing at "e.Id", I have a warning from VS telling me:

> Argument type 'lambda expression' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'

I really don't understand why it gives me this error. I checked another project and it's working fine. Maybe I miss a reference or something...any idea?

Comment: Have you tried another name for your variable ..

Comment: How is `UsersSet` declared? How is `Id` declared?

Comment: All is generated by entity engine. I just designed the classes with the designer integrated in Visual Studio. And yes I tried another name it doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain UsersSet is some kind of a collection of `User` instances then you can try

```
var t = from User e in entity.UsersSet
        where e.Id == 1
        select e;
```

Comment: question is tagged linq to entities - if `UsersSet` is indeed an entity your answer doesn't change anything since it's strongly typed already, if it is not it won't work either even if you try to cast - in summary: I don't know how this would help.

Comment: @BrokenGlass if  UsersSet it's a non-generic collection, e will be of type object and one will have to explicitly state the type of the elements in it.

Comment: Wow...problem solved. And it's so so foolish... In fact I just missed a System.Linq using that VS didn't alert me. What a luck that I have resharper that found the problem when I tried to strongly type the reference. So I mark your answer accepted as it helped me !

Answer (score 4):

This is a little late, but I just googled this exact problem (and ended here).

I found the above solution did fix it, but then it could also be fixed by just adding "using System.Linq;" to the top resolved the issue.